# running total with range and condition

Tags: mysql, sql

i have problem with my SQL syntax but i still a novice programmer so i don't know what the error message meant.

here's my code:

```
set @csum = 0;
select b.nama as divisi, a.nama, a.tgl, a.act, a.L_mulai, a.L_selesai, a.tot_jam, a.ket, (CASE WHEN a.act = 'lembur' THEN @csum = @csum + a.tot_jam ELSE @csum = @csum - a.tot_jam ) as `total jam`
FROM tbl_rkp_lemburtj AS a
LEFT JOIN tbl_bagian AS b ON a.Divisi = b.id
WHERE a.nama = 'Rofiq'
order by a.id;
```

please tell me what must i do to correct it.

here's the error message i got:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ') as `total jam` FROM tbl_rkp_lemburtj AS a LEFT JOIN tbl_bagian AS b ON a.Div' at line 1
```

i expect the result to be like this:
[image]

column total jam is running total of tot_jam with parameter **if act is lembur than add, else if act is tj then subtract**

Comment: share shample data and expected output

Comment: avoid using general title for your question and don't forget mention the error or output in your question.

Comment: As far as the error message is concerned every case must have an END, but this looks like an attempt to literally convert something procedural to something sql which you should avoid instead read up on aggregate functions https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html(and elsewhere) and study @ϻᴇᴛᴀʟ answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a `variable` to get the `sum()`, use this query.

```
select b.nama, a.nama, a.tgl, a.act, a.L_mulai, a.L_selesai, a.tot_jam, a.ket
    , sum(CASE WHEN a.act = 'lembur' THEN a.tot_jam ELSE 0 END) as `total jam`
FROM tbl_rkp_lemburtj AS a
LEFT JOIN tbl_bagian AS b ON a.Divisi = b.id
WHERE a.nama = 'Rofiq'
order by a.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to get a `SUM()` based on the logic inside your `CASE` statement, then you can try something like this:

```sql
SELECT b.nama, a.nama, a.tgl, a.act, a.L_mulai, a.L_selesai, a.tot_jam, a.ket, 
  SUM (
    CASE 
      WHEN a.act = 'lembur' THEN a.tot_jam -- Add "tot_jam"
      ELSE (-1) * a.tot_jam -- Subtract "tot_jam"
    END 
  ) AS total jam
FROM tbl_rkp_lemburtj AS a
LEFT JOIN tbl_bagian AS b ON a.Divisi = b.id
WHERE a.nama = 'Rofiq'
ORDER BY a.id
;
```

This will do a `SUM()` of all the rows based on the evaluated expression inside the `CASE`.  So if `a.act = 'lember'`, then add `tot_jam` to the sum, otherwise subtract it.